# Kotlin Filter list with multiple conditions - Return Either error or valid items

Tags: kotlin, filter, either

I'm having a kotlin list of objects `List<A>`

```
data class A (
 type : enum (TypeA, TypeB, TypeC)
)
```

I want to filter the list to find valid items and return `Either` error or valid items

1. If type is TypeA return error
2. If type is TypeB do some more check and if failed return error

Below is one way to achieve it

```
val a: List<A> = listOf(...)

fun validate(
      list: List<A>,
  ): Either<Error, List<A>> {
    val filteredList = ArrayList<A>()

    list.forEach { l ->
      when (l.type) {
        TypeA -> {
          if (some condition)
              return Either.Left(ErrorA)
        }
        TypeB ->
            return Either.Left(ErrorB)
        TypeC ->
            return Either.Left(ErrorC)
        else -> {
          filteredList.add(l)
        }
      }
    }
    return Either.Right(filteredList)
  }
```

Looking for a kotlin way of achieving with expressions

Comment: that class A code is invalid kotlin, and your "old school way" demonstrates something completely else with a different class. Can you elaborate more of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to filter a list to get some valid items. I have multiple conditions based on which if some errors are there, I will throw a validation error. If all conditions are met I will return only valid items

Comment: Maybe you can show us some more code, and some examples of expected outputs given certain inputs

Comment: @IvoBeckers I've edited the question to add some example

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are maybe able to link the error to the enum. But in that case you might be able to add this function to the enum and do this for example.

```
class ErrorA : Error()
class ErrorB : Error()
class ErrorC : Error()
val condition = true

data class A (val type : AType)

enum class AType {TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD;
    fun getError() : Error? =
        when(this) {
            TypeA -> if (condition) ErrorA() else null
            TypeB -> ErrorB()
            TypeC -> ErrorC()
            else -> null
        }
}


fun validate(list: List<A>): Either<Error, List<A>> = 
    list.firstOrNull { it.type.getError() != null }?.type?.getError()?.left() ?:
    list.filter { it.type.getError() == null }.right()
```

I'm not sure if it can be made more efficient in a way because with this solution the list gets iterated twice but at least it's a single expression solution